# bash script array to memoize fibonacci sequence

Tags: linux, bash, dynamic-programming, fibonacci, memoization

Unable to save Fibonacci values to an associative array for momoization. This script takes a Fibonacci index as an argument and returns the associated value sequence value. On each script execution a new sequence is generated from 1 to the argument value. Memoization should decrease the overall runtime.

## fab.sh

```
if [ -f log.txt ]; then
  rm log.txt
fi

# initialize SAVED array
SAVED=()

# populate saved with $1 of 0's
for i in $(eval echo {0..$(($1-1))}); do
  SAVED[i]=0
done

fib () {
  local currentIndex=$1

  if [ "$currentIndex" -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo 0
  elif [ "$currentIndex" -eq 1 ] ; then
    echo 1
  elif [[ ${SAVED[$currentIndex]} -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo 'MEMOIZED' >> log.txt
    echo ${SAVED[$currentIndex]}
  else
    SAVED[$currentIndex]=$((`fib $[$currentIndex - 1]`+`fib $[$currentIndex - 2]`))
    echo ${SAVED[@]} >> log.txt
    echo ${SAVED[$currentIndex]}
  fi
}

if [[ $1 -eq 0 ]]
then
  echo "Sequence limit must be at least 1"
elif [[ $1 -gt 0 ]]
then
  fib $(($1 - 1)) 
fi
```

if fab.sh is ran using `$ source fab.sh 5`:

```
$ 3
```

It is printing the correct value but memoization is not functioning.

The log.txt file out is:

```
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 2 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 3
```

It seems like the 'SAVED' array is being reset or the assigned values aren't persisting. Since the SAVED array is a global variable I would think this would work. It could have something to do with how bash handles recursive functions.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why bash? For education?

Comment: Yes, for education.

Comment: Why an associative array? It sounds like you would do better with a normal indexed integer array. You want to be able to ask what the Xth entry would be, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
SAVED[$currentIndex]=$((`fib $[$currentIndex - 1]`+`fib $[$currentIndex - 2]`))
```

you probably wanted to write

```
SAVED[currentIndex]=$((`fib $((currentIndex - 1))` + `fib $((currentIndex - 2))`))
```

However, that wouldn't solve the actual problem. As we can see from your log, the memoization array has at all times at most one entry. How is it possible that the last entry is filled, but the entries which are needed to compute that last entry are 0? The answer is *»subshells«*!

When you call your function using a subshell `$(fib ...)`, the changes that function makes on variables are only inside the subshell.
To work around the problem, you have to either use a file for memoization or find a way to call your function without a subshell.

Here is how I would have written that scrip, if I were forced to use your current approach. Please note that there are better ways to compute the fibonacci numbers and better languages to program these computations in.

```
#! /bin/bash
memo=(0 1)
fib() {
        >&2 printf %s "fib($1) memo=(${memo[*]}) => "
        local n="$1"
        if [ "${memo[n]+x}" ]; then
                >&2 echo lookup
                return
        fi
        >&2 echo compute
        fib "$((n-1))"
        fib "$((n-2))"
        ((memo[n]=memo[n-1]+memo[n-2]))
}
fib "$1"
echo "${memo[$1]}"
```

Lines starting with `>&2` are only there to print debug information; you can delete them. To suppress debug output, run the script as `script.sh 12 2> /dev/null`.

Improvements:

- To work around the subshell problem, don't echo the function result and store it using `var=$(fib ...)`, but remain silent and directly store the result in a designated global variable. Here we don't need a new variable because we already have the memoization array. We first call `fib x` to make sure that array entry `x` is there, then we access that entry with `memo[x]`.
- Instead of printing to a log, print debug information to `stderr` using `>&2 echo`.
- By storing `fib(0)=0` in the memoization array, we don't have to use an index offset.
- Embed the trivial cases 0 and 1 directly into the memoization array.
- Don't initialize the array with `0`.
  `${memo[n]}+x` expands to `x` if and only if `fib(n)` is already memoized.

Comment: I gave the change a run, but I'm still getting the same result. Memoization doesn't to be working or the SAVED array isn't keeping track of previous updates.

Comment: @ChristopherReece Updated the answer. That's actually a very interesting problem.

Comment: Wow! thank you @Socowi for getting back with such a sweet revision. I love how you built it up too by saying »subshells«! haha. I suspected that could be the problem, but didn't know enough about it. I gave the new script a run, and the elements are storing perfectly! Thanks to your detailed comments I've learned some new syntax as well. However, the fibonacci sequence is being incorrectly calculated. I'm about to head to bed, but I'm gonna let what you kindly taught me digest a little and take another crack at it tomorrow.

Comment: @ChristopherReece Thanks for the feedback. I made some small changes without checking and accidentially wrote `memo[n]=memo[n-1]+memo[n-1]` instead of `memo[n]=memo[n-1]+memo[n-2]`. Now the results should be correct. These are the results for the number 0 to 10: `0→0 1→1 2→1 3→2 4→3 5→5 6→8 7→13 8→21 9→34 10→55`.